# password validation using boolean

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I have to write a code that check if a password is valid.

The problem is when the password pass every condition I don't get any answer if it's. 
Right here you can see my code; I think I need to add something in my main function but I don't know what.

Is the *else if* statement not necessary?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a password : ");
        String passwordhere = in.nextLine();


        List<String> errorList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (!isValid(passwordhere, errorList)) {
            System.out.println("The password entered here is invalid");
            for (String error : errorList) {
                System.out.println(error);
            }

            System.out.print("Please enter a given  password : ");
            passwordhere = in.nextLine();
        }

    }

    public static boolean isValid(String passwordhere, List<String> errorList) {

        Pattern specailCharPatten = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Pattern UpperCasePatten = Pattern.compile("[A-Z ]");
        Pattern lowerCasePatten = Pattern.compile("[a-z ]");
        Pattern digitCasePatten = Pattern.compile("[0-9 ]");
        errorList.clear();

        boolean flag=true;



        if (passwordhere.length() < 8) {
            errorList.add("Password lenght must have alleast 8 character !!");
            flag=false;
        }
        if (!specailCharPatten.matcher(passwordhere).find()) {
            errorList.add("Password must have at least one specail character !");
            flag=false;
        }
        if (!UpperCasePatten.matcher(passwordhere).find()) {
            errorList.add("Password must have at least one uppercase character !");
            flag=false;
        }
        if (!lowerCasePatten.matcher(passwordhere).find()) {
            errorList.add("Password must have at least one lowercase character !");
            flag=false;
        }
        if (!digitCasePatten.matcher(passwordhere).find()) {
            errorList.add("Password must have at least one digit character !");
            flag=false;
        }
      else if(digitCasePatten.matcher(passwordhere).find()&&passwordhere.length() < 8&&
                specailCharPatten.matcher(passwordhere).find()&&lowerCasePatten.matcher(passwordhere).find()&&
                UpperCasePatten.matcher(passwordhere).find()){
            System.out.println("the pass is right");
            flag=true;

        }
        return flag;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (true) {
        if (!isValid(passwordhere, errorList)) {
            System.out.println("The password entered here is invalid");
            for (String error : errorList) {
                System.out.println(error);
            }

            System.out.print("Please enter a given  password : ");
            passwordhere = in.nextLine();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Password is valid!");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

or change just your method isValid like this :

```
    public static boolean isValid(String passwordhere, List<String> errorList) {

    Pattern specailCharPatten = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Pattern UpperCasePatten = Pattern.compile("[A-Z ]");
    Pattern lowerCasePatten = Pattern.compile("[a-z ]");
    Pattern digitCasePatten = Pattern.compile("[0-9 ]");
    errorList.clear();

    boolean flag=true;

    if (passwordhere.length() < 8) {
        errorList.add("Password lenght must have alleast 8 character !!");
        flag=false;
    }
    if (!specailCharPatten.matcher(passwordhere).find()) {
        errorList.add("Password must have at least one specail character !");
        flag=false;
    }
    if (!UpperCasePatten.matcher(passwordhere).find()) {
        errorList.add("Password must have at least one uppercase character !");
        flag=false;
    }
    if (!lowerCasePatten.matcher(passwordhere).find()) {
        errorList.add("Password must have at least one lowercase character !");
        flag=false;
    }
    if (!digitCasePatten.matcher(passwordhere).find()) {
        errorList.add("Password must have at least one digit character !");
        flag=false;
    }
    if(flag) System.out.println("the pass is right");

    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`else if( ... &&passwordhere.length() < 8 ...)` <-- sth wrong here.

But I think u don't need else if. After checking all, it's true or false.

So just

```
if (flag){
        System.out.println("the pass is right");
    }
```